# Responding to EKEventStore Change in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, eventkit, ekeventstore

According to the [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/updating_with_notifications):

> An EKEventStore object posts an EKEventStoreChanged notification whenever it detects changes to the Calendar database

The article then goes on to provide examples of how to do this in UIKit:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("storeChanged:"), name: .EKEventStoreChanged, object: eventStore)
```

In SwiftUI, I tried to do it this way:

```
let publisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("EKEventStoreChanged"))
```

and

```
.onReceive(publisher) { value in
    print("Store Changed")
}
```

But I never received any notification, and therefore the print statement was never called.

I also tried this:

```
let publisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name.EKEventStoreChanged)
```

but nothing changed.

---

**My Question**: How do I receive the `EKEventStoreChanged` notification in SwiftUI?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the UIKit example they use an instance of an EKEventStore in their call, do you have such object?

Comment: Yes, I do have an `EKEventStore` object.